# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) solution?

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api

I tried to get the weather from an API on a specific location by getting the value form an `input`  but that gives me the **400** error. It works only if I hardcode the location name in the URL, but that is not the functionality I'm looking for. I need it to be dynamically changed as the `input.value` is entered. Is there a better approach to it?

```
let input  = document.getElementById('input')
let searchButton = document.getElementById('button')
let showInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('conteinerInfo')
showInfo[0].setAttribute('id', 'mainddiv')
let divId = document.getElementById('mainddiv')

function getWeather () { 
fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=${input.value}&aqi=no`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => { 
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    divId.innerHTML =  'Temp' + ' ' + res.current.temp_c + "" + 'C'
})
})
}
getWeather()
```

Comment: I bet you're sending empty `q` parameter as you're running your function immediately as your JS or page loads. You're not waiting for user to actually enter something into the `input`.

Comment: When you debug, when the error occurs, what was the actual and complete URL being requested?  (You can observe the AJAX request in your browser's debugging tools.)  Does it match what you expected?  In what way does it differ?  What differences were you expecting?  Why?  If it matches what you expected, when you copy that exact URL and test it manually, what happens?

Comment: @willd Are those syntax errors in your post the same as in your real working code? The `;` on the end of the `fetch` call, and a missing ampersand (`&`) before your `q` property?

Comment: @Aleksandar: Good catch.  The *code shown* won't produce the error described, it would instead produce a syntax error.  Which would essentially invalidate any answer (including the obvious one of moving `addEventListener` to wrap the whole thing) as merely a guess, since we don't know the actual code being used or what other differences exist between the two.

Comment: @Aleksandar right I accidentally removed ```&``` when encrypting  my key the actual URL is ```http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXX&q=London&aqi=no
``` but it will only give me that location data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes very little sense:

```
function getWeather () { 
  fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=${input.value}&aqi=no`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => { 
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      divId.innerHTML =  'Temp' + ' ' + res.current.temp_c + "" + 'C'
    })
  })
}
getWeather()
```

What the code essentially says is:

1. Make an API request *immediately* when the page loads, using whatever default value is in the input.
2. After receiving a response from the API, create a click handler which will display that response to the user when they click the "search" button.

I suspect you intended to perform the API request *after* the user clicks the search button?  In which case you'd create a click handler which does exactly that... performs the API request and displays the result.  For example:

```
function getWeather () { 
  fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q=${input.value}&aqi=no`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => { 
    divId.innerHTML =  'Temp' + ' ' + res.current.temp_c + "" + 'C'
  })
}

searchButton.addEventListener('click', getWeather)
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thanks!